# C++ cin Input Validation in a While Loop

Tags: c++, validation, cin

My code is mostly working except for one minor issue. While it should only accept ints, it also accepts user input that start with an int, such as `6abc` for example. I saw a fix for this [here](https://jesushilarioh.com/how-to-validate-an-integer-in-c-plus-plus/), but it changed the input type to string and added a lot more lines of code. I'm wondering if there's an easier way to fix this:

```
int ID;
cout << "Student ID: ";
// error check for integer IDs
while( !( cin >> ID )) {
    cout << "Must input an integer ID." << endl ;
    cin.clear() ; 
    cin.ignore( 123, '\n' ) ; 
}
```

Comment: In short: No. If you want to verify the full input you need to read a full line as a string and then attempt to convert it to a number with validation. The [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and  [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) functions can be used for that.

Comment: You don't need to read whole lines, just whole words.  You can still use `cin >> ...` for that, but you will have to read into an intermediate `string` first and then convert that into an `int` for `ID`, and perform error handling of that conversion instead of (or in addition to) `>>`.

Comment: On a side note, don't hard-code the `count` for `cin.ignore()`, use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In a word - no.

But what you can do is instead read a whole word into a `std::string` first, and then convert that entire word into an `int`, checking for errors in that conversion, eg:

```cpp
int ID;
string input;

do
{
    cout << "Student ID: ";
    if (!(cin >> input))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    else
    {
        size_t pos = 0;
        try
        {
            ID = stoi(input, &pos);
            if (pos == input.size())
                break;
        }
        catch (const std::exception &) {}
    }
    cout << "Must input an integer ID." << endl;
}
while (true);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/NDoXKB)